# Как вернуть результат в методе после выполнение кода через vert.x event bus?

Tags: java, vert.x

```
public Completable method1(String msg) {
    Result result = method2(msg);

    if (result.isSuccess()) {
       return Completable.complete();      
    } else {
       return Completable.error(new Throwable());
    }
}



private Result method2(String msg) {
    CompletableFuture<Result> result = new CompletableFuture<>();

    vertx.eventBus().send("aaa.xxx.bbb", msg, reply -> {
       if (reply.succeeded()) {
          Result r = (Result) reply.result().body();
          result.complete(r);
       } else {
          result.completeExeptionally(reply.cause());
       }
    });

    return result.get();
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы после отправки на EventBus, и после выполнение EventBus вы вызвали какой то метод другой? можете разеснить?